# Add files to xcode project from git repository

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, github, repository

I am trying to add a git repository, specifically [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView), to my xcode project, so that when the git repository gets updated I get the updates automatically.

I have pulled the git in organizer, and cloned it, but how do I add it to a project so I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it as a submodule, but I never tried it before.